# android aapt in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-library, aapt

i saw some info regarding this question in several threads but non suited my condition.
I have an android application which i now need to customized some resources and code.
For the time being i have some problems using android library so i have an ant build that copies base resources and Assets plus specific ones to my android project and than changes the package name in the manifest as needed. All my activity have constant path and non relative to the package name so that's not an issue.
The problem is with the R object in the gen folder that is generated in the aapt. aapt does have a parameter to not use the android manifest package but another one, but it's available only if i use the ant build file, the parameters for the ADT are hard coded in the plugin.

has anyone found solution to this ? i mean i can always use ant task to change all R references (imports) but it looks to me error prone. Any way except wrapper script that wont do it on windows to customize aapt ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

again... no answer for my question, i'll start thinking you guys got something against me.
in short, i see there's no solution, the things  i can do:

1. use ant task that regexps all the import com....R; to the new package - disadvantage: even the smallest issue with the regexp i may mess something up in the code that will show only in runtime.
2. use wrapper script around aapt.exe or aapt binary that adds --custom-package my.package.name that even if i change the manifest package will keep the original R files, for both ant and eclipse - disadvantage, some: 1. on windows this needs to be an exec file as eclipse looks for one it took me a while to build one properly in C, on linux\mac this could be a script of any kind so we need 2 versions of it\ 2. every update to the SDK we need to install the wrapper all over again.
3. edit the ant tasks jar code to allow --custom-package and edit the adt source code to enable in the menu custom parameters - this is great feature that should be included! but the disadvantage is until the code is accepted (if it is accepted) and added to the SDK itself , i'll needs to merge my changes every new SDK emerges, unlike #2 this is a lot harder.

I chose option #2, for now i have executable for windows, and i'll check options for Linux and mac (probably simple bash script) once i'm there, and i'll create a python installation script and save it all in the svn along with my build project.

Good luck to everyone....